# Check cd,disk for defect option

Tags: 12.04

Let's say that i want to make a test. And i try to download and burn iso of Ubuntu on win7 that have avast anti virus, and that pc is maybe illegally activated... What will happen? Will it Check cd,disk for defect option work and really check state of media(check is it the live cd as it should be)?

I wonder what will happen if we have any unofficial change in Ubuntu live disk(viruses,errors etc), will it " Check cd/disk for defect " see as error and OS will not be able to install from cd? Or this option only check state of physical mistakes but not the data on that media or it check both!?
Could it that copy of Ubuntu still be good and official or it is corrupted ...

**Please do not delete part of post, all this is hypothetical question...**

Answer (score -1):

```
 fsck.ext4 [-panyrcdfvtDFV] [-b superblock] [-B blocksize]
        [-I inode_buffer_blocks] [-P process_inode_size]
        [-l|-L bad_blocks_file] [-C fd] [-j external_journal]
        [-E extended-options] device

Emergency help:
 -p                   Automatic repair (no questions)
 -n                   Make no changes to the filesystem
 -y                   Assume "yes" to all questions
 -c                   Check for bad blocks and add them to the badblock list
 -f                   Force checking even if filesystem is marked clean
 -v                   Be verbose
 -b superblock        Use alternative superblock
 -B blocksize         Force blocksize when looking for superblock
 -j external_journal  Set location of the external journal
 -l bad_blocks_file   Add to badblocks list
 -L bad_blocks_file   Set badblocks list
```

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from man page, could you elaborate, add instructions with their explanation .